Fresh Install, DB Error: Constraint Violation, no logs
I just did a clean install of CiVi CRM and I get: "DB Error: constraint violation" when I click the 'CiviCRM' link in the Drupal 10 toolbar.

I have checked the debugging and troubleshooting pages in the docs, however I can't get a detailed error:

No log files present in ConfigAndLog (permissions set to 775 on that folder)
No detailed error message
Can't access admin area to enable debugging
Nothing in Apache error logs

Any thoughts on how to get a detailed error message out of this?

Logout and login back
